# Problem with Appendix numbering in latex shell for the American Economic Journal Macro

Tags: numbering, documentclass, appendix

I am editing a paper for the AEA American Economic Journal Macroeconomics; the latex shell they provide \documentclass[AEJ]{AEA}  prevents the Appendix sections to display their Alphanumeric labels:   First Appendix, Second appendix  appear instead of  A. First Appendix, B. Second appendix , and so on

Labels are printed correctly for  subsections and equations though

Any ideas to fix the problem?

thanks, Francesco

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: If they provide a class for you to use giving a particular layout then it is safe to assume that that is the layout they want. Don't try and change it.

Answer (score 1):

The `AEA` document class does a very precise choice: after `\appendix`, the `\section` command is redefined to use `\@startappsection` instead of the kernel `\@startsection`. This command differs from the standard in two aspects:

1. it disallows `\section*`
2. it calls `\@appsect` instead of `\@sect`

The `\@appsect` command differs from `\@sect` in a small but decisive detail: in the part where the title is typeset it omits `\@svsec`, which is the bit responsible for printing the section number.

This allows to conclude that they *don't* want numbered appendices.

On the other hand, subsections *are* numbered. So a workaround could be to use

```
\appendix
\section{Appendix}

\subsection{First appendix}

Text

\subsection{Second appendix}

Text
```